# Make Python Lists Into Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm reading in data and want to make a two-dimensional array. I have nine separate datasets and after I read in all of them, I'd like a 9Xwhatever array. Right now, when I ask for the shape of tmax, it gives me nine separate lists while I'm in the loop and only one list for only one of the datasets when I'm outside the loop. How do I merge them all into a two-dimensional array?

```
import numpy as np

citydata = ['bcm2.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt',
    'ccsm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt',
    'pcm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt']


for x in range(0,len(citydata),1):

    data = np.genfromtxt(citydata[x], skip_header=1)
    tmax = (data[:,3]*(9./5.))+32.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import numpy as np

citydata = ['bcm2.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt',
'ccsm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt', 
'pcm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt']

tmax = []
for cd in citydata:
    data = np.genfromtxt(citydata[x], skip_header=1)
    tmax.append((data[:,3]*(9./5.))+32.)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
np.asanyarray([(np.genfromtxt(item, skip_header=1)[:,3]*(9./5.))+32 for item in citydata])
```

You files are all of the same length right?